# Prevent subsequent firings after initial .mousedown() event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

### Description of Problem ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxDSL/)):

Clicking the **#test** box multiple times creates layers of audio playing simultaneously and briefly pauses or staggers the `.fadeOut()` effect with each press. I want to prevent subsequent mousedown events from firing so that the `.fadeOut()` effect completes seamlessly and doesn't trigger additional audio plays.

### Code:

```
$('#test').mousedown(function() {
  var sound = new Audio("http://sounddogs.com/previews/3668/mp3/824357_SOUNDDOGS__ri.mp3");
  sound.play();
  $('#test').stop(true).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Comment: Like this? http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: That is very cool and I never knew that existed. Thank you for educating me!

Comment: Glad it helped...i wasn't sure if that was what you meant, so I'll make it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way:

```
var clicked = 0;
$('#test').mousedown(function () {
    if (clicked == 0) {
        clicked = 1;
        var sound = new Audio("http://sounddogs.com/previews/3668/mp3/824357_SOUNDDOGS__ri.mp3");
        sound.play();
        $('#test').stop(true).fadeOut(2000);
        setTimeout(function(){clicked = 0;}, 2000);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yxDSL/1/

Comment: I've been implementing this solution in other areas of my code and it wasn't working here; turns out the problem was I was resetting my ``clicked`` variable by calling another function. Just needed to move it beyond the scope and the problem was solved. This is by far the best solution though, and it never occurred to me to use setTimeout for the reset. So simple, yet so brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This will fire an event a single time: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#test').one('click',function() { //would only trigger on first click
  var sound = new Audio("http://sounddogs.com/previews/3668/mp3/824357_SOUNDDOGS__ri.mp3");
  sound.play();
 $('#test').stop(true).fadeOut(2000);

 $('#test').click(function(){ // for subsequent click write the function inside this

 });
});
```

Comment: I had no idea the .one() function even existed. This will be extremely helpful in the future but doesn't quite suite my needs for this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This'll do the trick...

```
$('#test').mousedown(function() {
  var sound = new Audio("http://sounddogs.com/previews/3668/mp3/824357_SOUNDDOGS__ri.mp3");
  sound.play();
  $('#test').unbind("mousedown").stop(true).fadeOut(2000);`
});
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. It never even crossed my mind to use the .unbind() function for something like this. The more you know...

Comment: No problemo, short and simple :)